# (sml) Syntax error?

Tags: types, functional-programming, sml

I have this function that checks a list of parsers if they work or not. I get error: EQUALO LPAREN FN. Any help?

```
fun oneOf [] = fn inp => NONE
 | oneOf (p::ps) = (fn inp => case parse p inp of
       NONE => oneOf ps inp
     | SOME (v,out) => SOME (v,out))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function defined with `fn` can have multiple cases just like a function defined with `fun`. So you can write something like `fun pat1 => exp1 | pat2 => exp2`. This means that when the SML parser sees the `|` at the beginning of line 2, it assumes that it belongs to the `fn` on line 1, not to the `fun` (because the `fn` came more recently). So when it reaches the `=`, it's confused because it expected a `=>`.

To fix your issue surround the `fn` on line 1 with parentheses.